# stacking syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

What this is about is that I want to know the age of individuals in the db based on their social security number. So sysdate - their birth date in a fitting format. Result wanted: John, Doe, 45,6 years. Table data:

Table:

```
pnr VARCHAR2(13) value'19790343-7899'
```

I must be missing something obvious. Here is the code I have so far: (some test code included)

Everything about dates

--Full code, attempts below --

```
declare 
 cursor c_åldrar is 
 select fnamn,enamn,(sysdate - to_date(substr(pnr,1,6),'yyyymm')) / 365 
   from bilägare;

begin 
   for rec in c_åldrar 
   loop 
     dbms_output.put_line(rec.fnamn||', '||rec.enamn||', '||rec.pnr||', '||sysdate); 
   end loop; 
end; 
/

-- Attempt 1 
   select fnamn,enamn,sysdate - to_date(substr(pnr,1,6),'yyyymm') 
     from bilägare;

-- Attempt 2 
    select fnamn,enamn,(sysdate - to_date(substr(pnr,1,6),'yyyymm')) / 365 
      from bilägare;
```

Comment: to_date(substr(pnr,1,6)||'01','yyyymmdd')

Answer (score 0):

This is, obviously, very approximate result as

- you don't know the accurate date of birth (year and month yes, but day?)
- years don't have 365 years; what about leap years

Therefore, our John has about 40 years. Happy birthday to John.

```
SQL> with bilagare (fnamn, enamn, pnr) as
  2    (Select 'John', 'Doe', '19790343-7899' from dual)
  3  select fnamn,
  4         enamn,
  5         round((trunc(sysdate) - to_date(substr(pnr, 1, 6), 'yyyymm')) / 365, 1) yrs
  6  from bilagare;

FNAM ENA        YRS
---- --- ----------
John Doe       40,1

SQL>
```

Comment: declare
cursor c_åldrar is select fnamn,enamn,pnr from bilägare;

begin
  for rec in c_åldrar loop
     dbms_output.put_line(rec.fnamn||', '||rec.enamn||', '||round((trunc(sysdate) - to_date(substr(pnr, 1, 6), 'yyyymm')) / 365, 1)||', '||sysdate);
  end loop;
end;
/ 
Thanks! But I get 

ORA-06550: line 6, column 100:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PNR' must be declared

Hmm isn't pnr declared via the cursor declaration?

Comment: It is, but you have to reference it via cursor variable, i.e. `rec.pnr`, not just`pnr`.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it :) Thanks